# PHP product page make category and subcategory link

Tags: php, hyperlink, categories, product

Everything works with this code but i want to have a link from product.php back to category and subcategory.

i have 3 parent categories, page1.php, page2.php and page3.php
also for those i have subcategories page1.php?subcat=1,2,3,4   page2.php?subcat=1,2,3,4

This is php code iam using to product.php

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id= $_GET['id'];
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result2);
if ($count > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
$pid = $row["id"];
$pname = $row["name"];
$pprice = $row["price"];
$pnoncategoryid = $row["noncategoryid"];
$pdesc = $row["desc"];
}

// gjeje emrin e categorise dhe nencategorise
$result3=mysql_query("select * from noncategory WHERE ncid=$pnoncategoryid");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
$noncategoryname = $row["ncname"];
$categoryid = $row["categoryid"];
}

$result4=mysql_query("select * from category WHERE cid=$categoryid");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
$categoryname = $row["cname"];
}
//mbaro
```

At category and subcategory i want to have link:

```
<h3><?php echo $pname; ?></h3>
<div class="pbr"></div>
<h4>Category:</h4>
<p class="price"><?php echo $categoryname; ?> / <?php echo $noncategoryname; ?></p>
<div class="pbr"></div>
<h4>Description:</h4>
<p class="desc"><?php echo $pdesc; ?></p>
<div class="pbr"></div>
<h4>Price:</h4>
<p class="price"><?php echo $pprice; ?> <?php echo _valuta_ ?></p>
```

Sorry for my bad english, hope some1 understand me :))

Comment: What is $_GET['id'] doing, shouldn't it be $_GET['subcat']

Comment: You get a product by id, it has subcat (noncat) as parameter and from noncat you get the parent (cat) right?

Comment: @BrandenStilgarSueper $_GET['id'] used for product.php?id=1 and $_GET['subcat'] used at category.php?subcat=1

Comment: @Neograph734 yes right, so i have all ids and all i want is to make a Category and Subcategory linkable. ps: if categoryid is 1, the href will be category1.php if categoryid is 2, the href will be category2.php..

Comment: I've updated the answer below... Both lines should replace `<?php echo $categoryname; ?> / <?php echo $noncategoryname; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to transform text into a hyperlink. Like this?

```
<?php echo "<a href='category".$categoryid.".php'>".$categoryname."</a>"; ?> / 
<?php echo "<a href='category".$categoryid.".php?subcat=".$pnoncategoryid."'>".$noncategoryname."</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: Similar to this but the php page name isnt same as $categoryname !!

Comment: if $categoryid = 3; echo Category1.php

Comment: Then you should check the corresponding name in the database, as far as I can see this is correct.